# jquery breaks angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm relatively new to angular and after hours of debugging i found some incompatibility when adding jquery. The directive works fine without jquery but breaks with it :/

Here is a plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/sRwqrWV1ha4Dp7lvsSAg?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce, $compile) {

    $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<button ng-click="testAlert()">Submit</button>');  

    $scope.testAlert = function () {
        alert('testing');
    };
```

});

Comment: Maybe I don't get the question. But why use trustAsHtml at all. Your plunker works fine without it. Jquery present or not. http://plnkr.co/edit/vPBFWfKV7toPquQFtozH?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that `$sce.trustAsHtml` does not return HTML string, and jQuery overrides the `.html` method.

You can fix the issue by:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function (html) {
                ele.html(html.$$unwrapTrustedValue());
                $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $sce, $compile) {

    $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<button ng-click="testAlert()">Submit</button>');

    $scope.testAlert = function () {
        alert('testing');
    };

});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2LebowpYm3NOouqCe88u?p=preview)

**NOTE**: This solves the problem but I don't find using `$$unwrapTrustedValue` as a good practice. Better solution will be to have a template which binds to `attrs.dynamic`.

This is a kind of better solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/xjS9gTJfyXvTL4LNzXub?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template: '<span ng-bind-html="dynamic" ng-click="method()"></span>',
        scope: {
            dynamic: '=',
            method: '&'
        }
    };
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $sce, $compile) {
    $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<button>Submit</button>');
    $scope.testAlert = function () {
        alert('testing');
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div dynamic="trustedHtml" method="testAlert()"></div>
```